# Clearing old data from sys.stdout in Python

Tags: python

There's something I don't get when writing to sys.stdout in Python.What I want is to write some strings into stdout without preprending the stuff which already has been written before that.

So doing this:

```
 while True:

    sys.stdout.write("k")
    sys.stdout.flush()

 sys.stdout.write("d")
```

After some "k" data has been written into stdout in a loop I need to write some new data afterwards,which is "d" for the sake of example.
I am  getting : "k d" in the output."K" from the loop writes is still in stdout.

What I want to get is just "d" .

Why?
How can I clear the stdout before writing new data into it?

Btw,using print() instead still accumulates the old data into final output.

Using python 2.7 on Linux

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. What exactly do you mean by "clearing" stdout? What should happen to the stuff already written to the console?

Comment: See my update.I just want to see in the terminal the last written string

Comment: Well of course the `k` is printed. You printed it, and then on top of that you flushed `stdout` to force it to be printed immediately! If you don't want something printed, don't... print... it?

Comment: Writing a carriage return (ASCII 13) between the `k` and the `d` might work, depending on your use case. It would help us to help you if you explained where you're going with all this. To me, the question has a strong feel of the XY Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @kindall no, I do have to print "k" but one line before "d".I want to print "d" in a completely new line.

Comment: @MichaelIV: With respect, this is the most confusingly worded question I have seen for some time. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminals don't work that way.  `flush` just flushes the *buffer* (i.e. characters that may not have been printed to screen yet), it does not clear the screen.

If you want to erase one character, you need to print a literal backspace control character, and then print something *over* your previous output (like a space):

```
sys.stdout.write("\b ")
```

However.  Your asking this belies a deep misunderstanding of how terminals work.  Think of it like a text processor - there is text on the screen, and a cursor (which is invisible).  You need to tell the cursor what to do to manipulate the text on the screen.  Since the cursor is always in overwrite mode, a trick that is often useful is to go back to the start of the line:

```
 sys.stdout.write("\r")
```

and overwrite your data on that line.  Note that if your new data is of lesser length than your previous data, this will leave some amount of previous data on the screen.

There are other tricks you can use if neither of these fits your bill, like outputting [terminal control sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) to stdout.

(also, unless you have a specific need for using `sys.stdout`, just use `print`.)

Comment: Good!sys,stdout.write("\r") helped as my last print is longer.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I do have to print "k" but one line before "d".I want to print "d" in a completely new line.

Simply write a newline between the two:

```
sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Or just use `print`, which adds an implicit newline at the end:

```
print "k"
print "d"
```

Comment: If using print "d"  it adds "k" to the beginning.Just checked that.Also,if using sys.stdout.write("\n") this space  still prepends the "k" from previous print so that I am getting "k" on the new line (after original "K" has been printed) and then "d"